# Error: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a driving simulator. The game works fine inside the Unity Editor but when I compile a standalone application and open it, it instantly crashes after the splash images. Below are the contents of the error log file (but certain names have been censored for privacy reasons). The problem appears to be with Unity's DLLs and not my code. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

```
C2 Driving Sim by <Company Name> [version: Unity 2020.1.0b7_6cfebb967dcd]

UnityPlayer.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module UnityPlayer.dll at 0033:388e90ba.

Error occurred at 2020-11-19_153936.
D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\C2 Driving Sim.exe, run by lowji.

59% physical memory in use.
16313 MB physical memory [6560 MB free].
8909306 MB process peak paging file [1527 MB used].
632 MB process peak working set [629 MB used].
System Commit Total/Limit/Peak: 16411MB/19877MB/31005MB
System Physical Total/Available: 16313MB/6560MB
System Process Count: 258
System Thread Count: 3944
System Handle Count: 126348
Disk space data for 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\...\C2 Driving Sim\Crashes\Crash_2020-11-19_073934963\': 13304684544 bytes free of 126710968320 total.

Write to location 0000000000000000 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x00007ffb39cc9918  RSI: 0x00007ffb39cc97c0  RAX:   0x0000000000000000
RBX:    0x0000000000000000  RCX: 0x0000000000000004  RDX:   0x00000000000005af
RIP:    0x00007ffb388e90ba  RBP: 0x0000087ec04b9000  SegCs: 0x0000000000000033
EFlags: 0x0000000000010246  RSP: 0x000000aa61f9e740  SegSs: 0x000000000000002b
R8:     0x000000000000005a  R9:  0x000000000000005e  R10:   0x0000000000000096
R11:    0x0000000000000246  R12: 0x0000087ec04b8740  R13:   0x00007ffb39cc98e0
R14:    0x0000000000000010  R15: 0x0000000000000000


Bytes at CS:EIP:
4c 89 3b 48 8b d3 4c 89 7b 08 48 89 43 10 48 8b 

Mono DLL loaded successfully at 'D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll'.


Stack Trace of Crashed Thread 15204:
0x00007FFB388E90BA (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB388E6AFA (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB388E314A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB388E635C (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38B54BE6 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38B0064E (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38A4C881 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38A4BBEB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38A4C687 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38C9A544 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Thread_YieldExecution
0x00000221CF435369 (UnityEngine.CoreModule) UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer.set_sprite()
0x00000221CF729543 (Assembly-CSharp) C2.UpdateOperatorLogo()
0x00000221CF71CBC3 (Assembly-CSharp) PIDS.ChangePIDS()
0x00000221CF70D253 (Assembly-CSharp) PIDS.Update()
0x00000220D28A84B0 (mscorlib) System.Object.runtime_invoke_void__this__()
0x00007FFB37D9CDA0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_get_runtime_build_info
0x00007FFB37D22112 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_perfcounters_init
0x00007FFB37D2B10F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke
0x00007FFB38C15FAD (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Thread_YieldExecution
0x00007FFB38C13372 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Thread_YieldExecution
0x00007FFB38BFC823 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Thread_YieldExecution
0x00007FFB38BFC908 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Thread_YieldExecution
0x00007FFB3899D2D0 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38AB5C47 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38AB5CE7 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB38AB9BD3 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB388A37AE (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFB388A25EA (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFB388A66BD (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFB388A779B (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.' (Address: 00007FF60F9A11F2)
0x00007FF60F9A11F2 (C2 Driving Sim) (function-name not available)
0x00007FFBB9587034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFBBAB5CEC1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

Module 1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput1_3.dll
Image Base: 0x00400000  Image Size: 0x0001e000
File Size:  107368      File Time:  2007-04-04_185422
Version:
   Company:    Microsoft Corporation
   Product:    Microsoft® DirectX for Windows®
   FileDesc:   Microsoft Common Controller API
   FileVer:    9.18.944.0
   ProdVer:    9.18.944.0

Crash Report configuration:
 * App Name: C2 Driving Sim
 * App Version: Unity 2020.1.0b7_6cfebb967dcd
 * Mono DLL: D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll
 * Bug Reporter App Path: 
 * Crash Report Path: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\...\C2 Driving Sim\Crashes
 * Is Editor: false

Crash Report metadata:

Additional report files:
 * "C:\Users\...\AppData\LocalLow\...\C2 Driving Sim\Player.log" (Output log file)



== [end of error.log] ==

== [Player.log] ==

Mono path[0] = 'D:/.../Programing/Unity/C2 Driving Sim/Builds/C2 Driving Sim_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'D:/.../Programing/Unity/C2 Driving Sim/Builds/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Initialize engine version: 2020.1.0b7 (6cfebb967dcd)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path D:/.../Programing/Unity/C2 Driving Sim/Builds/C2 Driving Sim_Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB (ID=0x1c02)
    Vendor:   
    VRAM:     2988 MB
    Driver:   27.21.14.5671
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in  1.396 seconds
D3D11 device created for Microsoft Media Foundation video decoding.
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 0) [0x80070057]
UnloadTime: 62.082600 ms
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;D:\...\Programing\Unity Backup\C2 Driving Sim;D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'lowji'
OS-Version: 10.0.0
D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\C2 Driving Sim.exe:C2 Driving Sim.exe (00007FF6471F0000), size: 671744 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2020.1.14.8036
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (00007FFBBAB10000), size: 2056192 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL:KERNEL32.DLL (00007FFBB9570000), size: 774144 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (00007FFBB8880000), size: 2916352 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\UnityPlayer.dll:UnityPlayer.dll (00007FFB6EFF0000), size: 28311552 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2020.1.14.8036
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll (00007FFBB9630000), size: 1703936 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll:win32u.dll (00007FFBB8380000), size: 139264 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (00007FFBB8EE0000), size: 172032 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll:gdi32full.dll (00007FFBB85C0000), size: 1085440 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll:msvcp_win.dll (00007FFBB82E0000), size: 643072 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll:ucrtbase.dll (00007FFBB8780000), size: 1048576 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll:ole32.dll (00007FFBB8FC0000), size: 1220608 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (00007FFBB8B70000), size: 1196032 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (00007FFBB1360000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll:combase.dll (00007FFBB9FF0000), size: 3493888 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll (00007FFBB9BF0000), size: 647168 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 7.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (00007FFBB8CA0000), size: 348160 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll:SETUPAPI.dll (00007FFBB90F0000), size: 4616192 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll:cfgmgr32.dll (00007FFBB83B0000), size: 319488 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll:bcrypt.dll (00007FFBB82B0000), size: 159744 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (00007FFBB8D60000), size: 696320 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (00007FFBB9C90000), size: 634880 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (00007FFBBA360000), size: 7602176 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (00007FFBB8E10000), size: 839680 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (00007FFBB9900000), size: 196608 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (00007FFB83960000), size: 1200128 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll:CRYPT32.dll (00007FFBB8460000), size: 1429504 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (00007FFBAB1B0000), size: 159744 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (00007FFBB9B80000), size: 438272 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (00007FFBB1130000), size: 1048576 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (00007FFBB6B20000), size: 53248 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (00007FFBAE2A0000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll:kernel.appcore.dll (00007FFBB60A0000), size: 73728 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll:bcryptPrimitives.dll (00007FFBB8230000), size: 520192 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (00007FFBB5CC0000), size: 651264 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll:shcore.dll (00007FFBB9F40000), size: 712704 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll:windows.storage.dll (00007FFBB6380000), size: 7946240 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll:Wldp.dll (00007FFBB7BD0000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll:profapi.dll (00007FFBB8160000), size: 155648 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
D:\...\Programing\Unity\C2 Driving Sim\Builds\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll:mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll (00007FFB81390000), size: 7790592 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: ''
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL:PSAPI.DLL (00007FFBB98F0000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (00007FFBB97D0000), size: 1134592 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll:d3d11.dll (00007FFBB3FF0000), size: 2506752 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll:dxgi.dll (00007FFBB6B60000), size: 995328 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhdc.inf_amd64_3e9ef682a1d3bf5b\nvldumdx.dll:nvldumdx.dll (00007FFBAB1E0000), size: 1056768 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 27.21.14.5671
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msasn1.dll:msasn1.dll (00007FFBB7D50000), size: 73728 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll:cryptnet.dll (00007FFBAFE90000), size: 200704 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptbase.dll:cryptbase.dll (00007FFBB7B40000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.DLL:WINTRUST.DLL (00007FFBB8400000), size: 393216 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll:imagehlp.dll (00007FFBB8B50000), size: 118784 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll:CRYPTSP.dll (00007FFBB7B20000), size: 98304 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll:rsaenh.dll (00007FFBB72E0000), size: 212992 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhdc.inf_amd64_3e9ef682a1d3bf5b\nvwgf2umx.dll:nvwgf2umx.dll (00007FFB771C0000), size: 44793856 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 27.21.14.5671
C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvspcap64.dll:nvspcap64.dll (00007FFB82D40000), size: 2809856 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 3.20.4.14
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll:ntmarta.dll (00007FFBB6F50000), size: 208896 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll:dxcore.dll (00007FFBB2170000), size: 241664 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll:clbcatq.dll (00007FFBB8F10000), size: 692224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2001.12.10941.16384
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll:wbemprox.dll (00007FFBB0A50000), size: 69632 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll:wbemcomn.dll (00007FFBB09C0000), size: 548864 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll:wbemsvc.dll (00007FFBB0310000), size: 81920 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll:fastprox.dll (00007FFBB0330000), size: 1093632 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amsi.dll:amsi.dll (00007FFBB0250000), size: 94208 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll:USERENV.dll (00007FFBB80E0000), size: 188416 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpOav.dll:MpOav.dll (00007FFBB0200000), size: 278528 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 4.18.1909.6
C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Total Security 20.0\x64\antimalware_provider.dll:antimalware_provider.dll (00007FFBAFFD0000), size: 2252800 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 30.147.89.0
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll:MMDevApi.dll (00007FFBB1F30000), size: 544768 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll:DEVOBJ.dll (00007FFBB7F10000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (00007FFBB1FE0000), size: 1576960 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll:powrprof.dll (00007FFBB8090000), size: 307200 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll:UMPDC.dll (00007FFBB8070000), size: 73728 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: ''
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\resourcepolicyclient.dll:resourcepolicyclient.dll (00007FFBB5D80000), size: 81920 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput1_3.dll:xinput1_3.dll (0000000000400000), size: 122880 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 9.18.944.0
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll:dcomp.dll (00007FFBB4F10000), size: 1986560 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (00007FFBB6070000), size: 192512 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll:textinputframework.dll (00007FFBA31E0000), size: 1032192 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll:CoreMessaging.dll (00007FFBB57F0000), size: 991232 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll:CoreUIComponents.dll (00007FFBB5490000), size: 3530752 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll:wintypes.dll (00007FFBB4DB0000), size: 1400832 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll:mswsock.dll (00007FFBB7950000), size: 434176 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll:gpapi.dll (00007FFBB6B30000), size: 143360 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.572
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL:IPHLPAPI.DLL (00007FFBB7640000), size: 241664 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL:WINNSI.DLL (00007FFBB2BE0000), size: 45056 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (00007FFBBA350000), size: 36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (00007FFBA4480000), size: 1982464 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.488
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll:SspiCli.dll (00007FFBB8110000), size: 245760 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.19041.546

========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FFB6F5029CA (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F50042A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F4FCA7A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F4FFC8C (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F7740E6 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F71CAEE (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F6680A1 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F66740B (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F667EA7 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F8B46F4 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x000001D6D776C8A9 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer:set_sprite (UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer,UnityEngine.Sprite)
0x000001D6D7DD7733 (Mono JIT Code) C2:UpdateOperatorLogo ()
0x000001D6D7DCA4C3 (Mono JIT Code) PIDS:ChangePIDS ()
0x000001D6D7DC5543 (Mono JIT Code) PIDS:Update ()
0x000001D5D992AB80 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFB814BDB10 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_get_runtime_build_info
0x00007FFB81442902 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_perfcounters_init
0x00007FFB8144B95F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke
0x00007FFB6F83812D (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F8354C2 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F81E903 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F81E9E8 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F5B7680 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F6D23A7 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F6D2447 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFB6F6D63FC (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
  ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Es wurde versucht, auf eine unzulässige Adresse zuzugreifen.' (Address: 00007FFB6F4BCDEE)
0x00007FFB6F4BCDEE (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
  ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Es wurde versucht, auf eine unzulässige Adresse zuzugreifen.' (Address: 00007FFB6F4BBC2A)
0x00007FFB6F4BBC2A (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
  ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Es wurde versucht, auf eine unzulässige Adresse zuzugreifen.' (Address: 00007FFB6F4BFE1D)
0x00007FFB6F4BFE1D (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
0x00007FFB6F4C0EFB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
  ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Es wurde versucht, auf eine unzulässige Adresse zuzugreifen.' (Address: 00007FF6471F11F2)
0x00007FF6471F11F2 (C2 Driving Sim) (function-name not available)
0x00007FFBB9587034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFBBAB5CEC1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========

A crash has been intercepted by the crash handler. For call stack and other details, see the latest crash report generated in:
 * C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/IngeniousApplications/C2 Driving Sim/Crashes
```

Comment: Please add the content of mentioned `Player.log` .. is it possible you are using some external joystick or something your app doesn't have access to? Or are you maybe using some File IO where you don't have permissions?

Comment: Do you have any threading you put in your game?

Comment: @derHugo - yes I am using an external joystick. How can I check if my app has access to it? It does work perfectly in the Unity Editor though. And I'm pretty sure my File IOs are ok because I am only accessing files in the persistent data path of the application.

Comment: @BugFinder - what kind of threading? I dont think I added any :\

Comment: Well potentially any kind

Comment: @BugFinder it seems to be the Unity main thread though

Comment: @JiYuanLow as said please provide the player.log content. Also maybe show us the code for the FileIO (including the exact paths you are using) and maybe the code/settings for the joystick

Answer (score -2):

I do not know what exactly I did but I managed to solve the issue. There were many small changes I made to the code in ten files and I cannot identify which one (or which few) helped solve the issue. To the commentors, thanks for your help anyway!